# Why is my ball using acceleration as velocity?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

I got an object of type `ball` which is a subclass of the class `Particle`. This class has three members `position`, `velocity` and `acceleration` of type `Vector`.

On each frame, when `myball.update` is called, its velocity is summed to the position and the acceleration is summed to the velocity. Then the ball is drawn on the screen. Anyway for some unclear motive whatever value I give as a velocity the ball doesn't move, but it moves in non - accelerated uniform movement if I give a value as the acceleration.

Here are my classes Vector:

```
class Vector {
    private:
        void updateC() {
            x = cos(a) * l;
            y = sin(a) * l;
        }
        void updateT() {
            a = atan2(y, x);
            l = sqrt(x * x + y * y);
        }
    public:
        float x = 0, y = 0;
        float a = 0, l = 0;
        Vector() {

        }
        Vector(float nx, float ny): x(nx), y(ny) {
            updateT();
        }
        void X(float nx) {
            x = nx;
            updateT();
        }
        void Y(float ny) {
            y = ny;
            updateT();
        }
        void A(float na) {
            a = na;
            updateC();
        }
        void L(float nl) {
            l = nl;
            updateC();
        }
        Vector operator +(Vector other) {
            return Vector(x + other.x, y + other.y);
        }
        Vector operator -(Vector other) {
            return Vector(x - other.x, y - other.y);
        }
        Vector operator *(float m) {
            Vector result(x, y);
            result.L(l * m);
            return result;
        }
        void operator +=(Vector other) {
            x += other.x;
            y += other.y;
            updateT();
        }
        void operator -=(Vector other) {
            x -= other.x;
            y -= other.y;
            updateT();
        }
        void operator *=(float m) {
            l *= m;
            updateC();
        }
    };
```

Particle:

```
class Particle {
    public:
        Vector position;
        Vector velocity;
        Vector gravity;
        Particle() {}
        Particle(Vector np, Vector nv = Vector(0, 0), Vector na = Vector(0, 0)): position(np), velocity(na), gravity(na) {}
        void accelerate(Vector a) {
            velocity += a;
        }
        void update() {
            position += velocity;
            velocity += gravity;
        }
};
```

And ball:

```
class ball: public Particle {
    public:
        ball(Vector p, Vector v, Vector a): Particle(p, v, a) {}
        void update() {
        Particle::update();
            graphics.circle("fill", position.x, position.y, 10);
        }
};
```

So, as I said before, if I initialize `myball` with a velocity different than 0, the ball still won't move, but it will move  if I inititialize it with an acceleration different than 0 using acceleration as velocity.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Why don't you have time component in position and velocity updates?

Comment: Your Vector class is not cool. It has x, y, a, l  as public. Also, parameters are passed to operators by value (Usually it is constant ref X& operator+=(const X& rhs)). You can try to change operators signatures. Also you can try to debug you code

Comment: @Unick "_Also you can try to debug the code_" right

Comment: @Unick should I set them as private and implement methods to get them? No thanks. It's slower and verbose (`myvector.getX()` instead of `myvector.x`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo in the Particle constructor:

```
 Particle(Vector np, Vector nv = Vector(0, 0), Vector na = Vector(0, 0)): position(np), velocity(na), gravity(na) {}
```

It must be:

```
 Particle(Vector np, Vector nv = Vector(0, 0), Vector na = Vector(0, 0)): position(np), velocity(nv), gravity(na) {}
```

Comment: I mean typo. You wrote `velocity(na)` instead of `velocity(nv)`

Comment: https://youtu.be/5JamMWk9D68 I knew it was something as easy as this, but couldn't recognize it. Thanks a lot.